# IPTables list only drop rules

Tags: iptables

I currently have quite a few rules on our server and I use this to monitor it:

iptables -vL

This displays packets hitting each rule, however is there a way to only display DROP rules? I'm not interested in seeing ACCEPT rules etc as it takes up too much room.

Comment: try using grep to diplay only interesting lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a shell script to execute this command and store the full output somewhere I would suggest using grep as bgtvfr suggested.

`iptables -vL | grep DROP >> logfile.txt`

Comment: As both btgvfr and inaki suggest, this is [the UNIX way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy).  +1 from me.